# How to handle multiple entities on the same form in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently creating a website with Symfony 4 and I am creating the register/login part of it.
My problem is that I have different type of users, so different entities with their own fields. There are just the email and password fields in common with all entities. So, I want to achieve just one form to register any entity. To select the user type, there is just a select field at the beginning of the form.

Moreover, I need a table for each type of user in database but the email need to be unique even between each table.

So, for now, I display the right fields calling a function with AJAX which return me the different data to create the right input. But struggle on validation at this point because I'm not using a FormBuilder.

And in the database, I have a table for all users but just with id, email, password and role and one table for each type of user with the user id(from the first table) and the remaining fields, proper to each type.

Am I on the right way or there is a better solution ? I'm a beginner in Symfony so I may miss out on an obvious solution.

Thanks

Comment: to get the entities in row, look at inheritance in doctrine. for your login-problem: look up the chain user providers.

Comment: Yes, I tried chain-providers but UniqueEntity on email doesn't work, it work on each table separetly but not on all. And my main problem is not login but the register form, to handle right entity depending on select value and validation

Comment: There must be a base User class, which all others extend, hence inheritance. This base User class should own an email field (which then is unique). That is mostly the difficult part. The other parts is just ... work. Writing UserProviders for all classes, handling registration correctly (probably won't work automatically), but apart from that, that's probably the right approach. inheritance in doctrine: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: You could also just make a normal User class, and load additional data depending on which "group" it belongs to. This is probably also very easy to handle in most other scenarios, since role-based access control is built into symfony's security component (including firewalls), and I have the feeling you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: I think too haha. Ok, I will try these solutions. Thanks !